# Async Await Behaviour

Tags: node.js, async-await, ionic4

A simple code to understand async/await is making me crazy.

I have a button on click on which i am reading some value from localstorage and showing it in an alert box. Before showing the alert i want to console.log the value.

If i understood async/await my code should d exactly that but it is working in reverse order. first the alert is coming and then the console.

//Method called on button click

```
findMyAge2() {
    this.getData("age").then(result => {
      console.log('Hi');
      myAge2 = result;
    });
    alert(myAge2);
  }

  async getData(key): Promise<any> {
    return await this.storage.get(`${key}`);
  }
```

Expected Result: 
in Console log :Hi
UI: Age

Actual Results: 
UI: Age
in Console log :Hi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is asynchronous by nature, so when you have a `Promise` returned, code continues execution and that `Promise` resolves some time afterward.

`async/await` is a way to control this flow of programming and can allow you to create Synchronous code that "awaits" the result of asynchronous execution.

Your problem here is that you want to return the promise from your `getData` function and `await` it in your `findMyAge2` function.

```
async function findMyAge2() {
  let result = await this.getData("age");
  console.log('Hi');
  myAge2 = result;
  alert(myAge2);
}

async getData(key): Promise<any> {
  return this.storage.get(`${key}`);
}
```

By adding `async` keyword to a function it will always now return a `Promise`. So you do not need to `await` in your `return` statement. That effectively does nothing. It would be like saying:

```
function getData(key) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    return localStorage.get(`${key}`).then(result => resolve(result))
  })
}
```

You don't need to await that result in local storage because the consumer should be calling `await` or `.then` on the result regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
findMyAge2() {
    this.getData("age").then(result => {
      console.log('Hi');
      myAge2 = result;
      alert(myAge2);
    });
  }

  async getData(key): Promise<any> {
    return await this.storage.get(`${key}`);
  }
```

Before you should wait to `alert` before data being retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

async/await works like with promises, which means, code gets executed and you don't know when it will finish, you just know that after if finishes, you want something else to be executed.

This is exactly what you put inside the "then" function, which is what gets executed after the 1st part (asyc getData) gets executed.

In the case of your code, the findMyAge2 gets called when you click the button, then it executes the getData and specifies what happens after getting the result from that call, within the "then" block.
Therefore you just have to move the alert, into "then" block, then you'll have the result you expect.

```
var myAge2;

findMyAge2() {
    this.getData("age").then(result => {
      console.log('Hi');
      myAge2 = result;
      alert(myAge2);
    });
}

async getData(key): Promise<any> {
    return await this.storage.get(`${key}`);
}
```